# Can I use TLS 1.2 or 1.1 (if 1.2 is not available) in .net when calling a web servivce?

Tags: .net, ssl, web

I would like to be able to use TLS 1.2, if a web service requires it, but also (for the time being) make calls using TLS 1.1 to services that do not support it.

Currently we are using ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol to set this in our code. (.net 4.0)  Is this already backwards compatible?  Or is it an all or nothing thing?  And if so, is there some way to OR things together?

Comment: You can specify multiple TLS using bitwise or as SecurityProtocolType is flag attribute .  System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls;

Comment: This will likely work, but hardcoding TLS versions in application code may not be the best option and could have unintended side effects (e.g., when TLS 1.3 becomes available).  It's better to configure this in the OS. More info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls

Comment: If you update to .NET 4.6 and target 4.6 in your app it should do what you want by default.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify multiple TLS using bitwise or as SecurityProtocolType is flag attribute .

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
```

Comment: Hi @Hakunamatata, Do you have a reference? This [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager.securityprotocol?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Net_ServicePointManager_SecurityProtocol) is saying *One of*. I could not find an official document that says you can combine. But the `SecurityProtocolType` enum values seem to indicate you can combine them.

Comment: I just found out that [this line of code for System.Net.ServicePointManager](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System/net/System/Net/ServicePointManager.cs#L263) does the same thing. So good enough reference for me :))

Comment: @FrankFajardo the enum has FlagsAttribute so that means you can combine them.